# ClickOnce Deployment in restricted environment

Tags: activex, clickonce, signed

I'm deploying a .Net 2.0 application using ClickOnce. The production intranet environment of my company will soon only allow the execution of signed ActiveX components. My app is signed, but I don't know if when this resctriction is active the browser will forbid the deployment of my app, because it is not an ActiveX.

Has anybody this same problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce does not require administrative privileges to install the application, it installs it under the user's profile. Also, it is not installed by the browser, it's more like it uses it to open the deployment manifest which in turn causes the ClickOnce engine to run and install the appliaction. Can you try it and see if it works?

RobinDotNet